# Как присвоить именам случайные значение из словаря Python?

Tags: python-3.x, случайные-числа, словари, dict

Всем привет!

Ситуация такая: есть словарь

`a = {1: [5, 100], 2: [10, 120], 3: [15, 130], 4: [20, 140], 5: [25, 150], 6: [30, 160], 7: [35, 170], 8: [40, 180], 9: [45, 190], 10: [50, 200]}`

нужно сделать так чтобы именам x, y, z были присвоены значения из этого словаря. Причем х - это ключ (т.е. 1, 2, 3 и т.д.) y - значение под индексом 0 (т.е. 5, 10, 15 и т.д.) z - значение под индексом 1 (т.е. 100, 120, 130 и т.д.). При этом сам процесс ссылки должен происходить рандомно.

Т.е. рандомным образом должна быть выбрана одна пара **ключь:значение** и объекты из этой пары должны быть соответственно присвоены именам x, y, z. Как это можно сделать?

Есть похожий пример

```
a = {1:100, 2:120, 3:130, 4:140, 5:150, 6:160, 7:170, 8:180, 9:190, 10:200}
```

который решается вот так

```
x, y = random.choice(list(a.items()))
```

Но тут идет присвоение на 2 переменные, а как сделать на 3 ?

P.S. если есть похожий вопрос с ответом - сорри за засорение форума, за ссылочку буду благодарен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
x, (y, z) = random.choice(list(a.items()))
print(x, y, z)
```

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек))
все работает)

Comment: @Andrey Gerbedz не за что)